# How can I reliably test for Snow Leopard inside a Makefile?

Tags: makefile, osx-snow-leopard

I've got to tweak my build just slightly on Snow Leopard, how can I easily test the platform?  uname -a doesn't seem to be returning anything particularly helpful.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
$ sw_vers -productVersion
10.5.8
```